# NHibernate: Is it possible for IUserType to convert a value to null and have it output as IS NULL in the resulting query?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

We are using NHibernate as our ORM.  We have a table that one of the columns has a custom IUserType mapped onto it.  The purpose of the IUserType is that depending on the type of connection we are using the value might be null or just an empty string.

So when we run this query depending on the underlying data storage the IUserType will convert the empty string to null
`Session.QueryOver<MyTable>().Where(t=>t.MyColumn == string.Empty).ToList()`
Witch creates this query
select * from MyTable where MyColumn = NULL

Looking at the NHibernate code there is this code

```
SqlStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlStringBuilder(4 * columnNames.Length);
var columnNullness = typedValue.Type.ToColumnNullness(typedValue.Value, criteriaQuery.Factory);

if (columnNullness.Length != columnNames.Length)
{
    throw new AssertionFailure("Column nullness length doesn't match number of columns.");
}

for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Length; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        sqlBuilder.Add(" and ");
    }

    if (columnNullness[i])
    {
        sqlBuilder.Add(columnNames[i])
                  .Add(Op)
                  .Add(parameters[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        sqlBuilder.Add(columnNames[i])
                  .Add(" is null ");
    }
}
return sqlBuilder.ToSqlString();
```

but column nullness is just based on the current value not the converted value this is from CustomType in NHibernate code

```
public override bool[] ToColumnNullness(object value, IMapping mapping)
{
    bool[] result = new bool[GetColumnSpan(mapping)];
    if (value != null)
        ArrayHelper.Fill(result, true);
    return result;
}
```

Is there anyway to have a IUserType convert a value to null and have the query come out as IS NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug (missing feature) for `IUserType` types.

It seems in your case you can implement custom type based on `AbstractStringType`. Something like:

```
[Serializable]
public class EmptyAsDbNullStringType : AbstractStringType
{
    public EmptyAsDbNullStringType() : base(new StringSqlType())
    {
    }

    public EmptyAsDbNullStringType(int length) : base(new StringSqlType(length))
    {
    }

    public override string Name => "EmptyAsDbNullString";

    public override void NullSafeSet(DbCommand st, object value, int index, bool[] settable,
        ISessionImplementor session)
    {
        base.NullSafeSet(st, ToDbValue(value), index, settable, session);
    }

    public override object NullSafeGet(DbDataReader rs, string name, ISessionImplementor session)
    {
        return FromDbValue(base.NullSafeGet(rs, name, session));
    }

    public override bool[] ToColumnNullness(object value, IMapping mapping)
    {
        return base.ToColumnNullness(ToDbValue(value), mapping);
    }

    private static object ToDbValue(object value)
    {
        return string.Empty.Equals(value) ? null : value;
    }

    private static object FromDbValue(object value)
    {
        return value ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

You might need to override some more members to make it work properly in all cases.

Comment: That is what I was guessing but wanted to ask in case I was missing something.  I will go check with NHibernate and see if it is something they are ok with me adding as a feature.  We are using Fluent-NHibernate for our mappings and just doing CustomType<OurIType> witch according to the documentation needs an IUserType.  I don't see anywhere in Fluent-NHibernate that takes an IType.  Do you know if there might be something in Fluent-NHibernate that I am missing? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `.CustomType<EmptyAsDbNullStringType>()` doesn't work? `IType` should also be accepted.

Comment: It might work the documentation just says it expects an IUserType.  I will try and see if it works.  Thanks